# What is the most intelligent way to store tiny SVG images in S3 Bucket for a single web page consumption?

Tags: amazon-s3

All image assets need to be loaded for home page (not the case where each image is for a different page).

If I understand correctly, if each image gets stored in a different bucket Object, then we are opening a new HTTP connection for each download.

Will it be faster if I store all SVGs within the same object?

Is it worth considering gzip compression? (or any other kind of compression?)

Comment: S3 buckets can each store tons of files. Why would you consider creating a new bucket for each file?

Comment: Any chance you could use CloudFront? It automatically handles connection multiplexing and compression, via http/2 and on-the-fly gzip respectively. So all your SVG files would be served over the same TCP connection. You can use S3 as a source for CloudFront.

Comment: I said bucket object, not bucket. I have never considered creating one bucket per image.

Comment: It looks like "object" is Amazon's terminology for "file". >:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up creating a composite SVG Sprite which plays well with CSS and other style post-processors. Size is very small and eliminates the overhead for more than one single HTTP request per page.